# Can you create a crosstab table using Excel's new dynamic functions?

Tags: excel, dynamic, formula, crosstab

I want to create a summary (sum or count) of a list of data based on two columns, showing all the unique items from the first column down the rows, and the unique items from the second columns across the columns, and the sum (or total) for each combination

I can do the sums with multiple formulae, but I'd like to try to do it in one

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I already have an answer which takes just three formulae, one each for the list of unique row and column items, and one to create all the table counts (and sums are easy to do instead)

If my two columns I want to compare are A and B, and I want my crosstab to start in D1 (say)

This formula gives me a unique sorted list of items in column A, down the page
The filter is used to exclude blanks, otherwise Excel will add a 0 at the bottom

```
D2 = SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")))
```

This formula gives me the unique sorted items from the second column, transposed to go along the columns

```
E1 = TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""))))
```

Then this formula goes in E2

```
E2 = COUNTIFS(A:A,D2#,B:B,E1#)
```